# Thumbunails slide is not working on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce

I'm using Yith Magnifier for woocommerce but the issue is when clicking on the images in thumbunail slides nothing happens, nomally it has to replace the main image with the clicked one !

Comment: Yith has dedicated support for plugin owners. This is not the place to discuss plugin support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was two files(product-image.php and product-thumbunail.php) in woocommerce were incompatible with the theme, so i replaced them with files from another version and it worked just fine.